# Usb ports does not work!

Tags: usb

I don't know what is actually happened to the mouse's usb port. This happens when the Ubuntu software updater was running and I don't know why the PC restarted itself. And I plug the mouse to another port and things just works fine. But the port is broken. I need help from you to fix broken usb port.

[image]

I have an early warning about the ibus has stop working or something else. And things just happened.

Comment: Error 71 is usually a power issue. Is the broken port part of a non-powered hub?

Comment: it might be a short in the mouse-cabel-plug,if possible try an other mouse and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Jos It is a back usb port

Comment: @trondhansen Oh yes, It works when I unplug and plug it again on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments a likely cause for your problem is a shorted wire in the mouse.

As the mouse gets older the movement of the wire will lead to wear so you might get a short circuit or a bad conection,to avoid this you can use a wireless mouse but they come with their own set of problems.

You can get the same problem if too many power hungry devices is on the same usb ports.

This is not the only cause for power problems in usb ports,it is the most likely cause so unpluging all the usb connectors is the first step in diagnosing this.